# Hardware-restricted root login

Tags: authentication, linux, server

I was thinking about how security on my Linux server can be increased and came up with this question: If most intrusions are performed by gaining remote access to machines, would it be possible and sensible to restrict admin user or maybe even root login by a hardware device? Meaning that it wouldn't be possible to log in as root if, for example, a certain USB device is not attached to server. Would that make sense or maybe even increase the complexity more than security?

The server is being administrated without any remote access/SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, I would add that most attackers don't directly log in via the console or ssh, but instead use bugs in other software in order to break out into a root shell or elevate their privileges. Adding 2-factor authentication or other mechanisms will definitely improve your security posture, but must be viewed as part of a larger overall hardening strategy.

Answer (score 0):

This is called two-factor authentication.  It already exists, though it may not be trivial to implement in all cases.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out it would be sort of 2-f auth. after I posted it. "It exists" in terms of other people had this idea already or there are ready-to-use tools?

Comment: @ScepticalJule An example done with TOTP and PAM. http://spod.cx/blog/two-factor-ssh-auth-with-pam_oath-google-authenticator.shtml

Comment: There's a PAM module for this: http://pamusb.org/.  It allows 2 factor authentication with a USB dongle.